# Set Text Size with a dimension got by a String

Tags: java, android

I'm using this function to get by Java a dimension from my dimens.xml file:

```
public static float getDimen(Context context, String name)
{
    Assert.assertNotNull(context);
    Assert.assertNotNull(name);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    int dimensionID = res.getIdentifier(name, "dimen", context.getPackageName());

    return res.getDimension(dimensionID);
}
```

This works like: `getDimen(mContext, "textsize_small")` and retrieves the "R.dimen.textsize_small" value (or at least it should).

```
<resources>
      <dimen name="textsize_small">10dp</dimen>
      <dimen name="textsize_medium">13dp</dimen>
      <dimen name="textsize_large">15dp</dimen>
      <dimen name="textsize_xlarge">17dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

So, after having this value I use it to set the TextSize of a TextView:

```
float textsize = getDimen(mContext, "textsize_" + object.getDesiredSize);
textview.setTextSize(textsize);
Log.d(TAG, "TextSize: " + textview.getTextSize());
```

EDIT:

I set `android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_small"` and used `getDimen(mContext, "textsize_small")`. In the first one the Log.d returns **15.0** and in the second one returns **22.5**

Is any type conversion missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>The answer is correct. You are running on a xhdpi device (nominally 360 pixels/inch) and you have defined your values as `dp`. So 10dp is 22.5 pixels (10 * 360 / 160 — where 160 is the default pixel density from which dp values are scaled). In other words, 22.5 pixels has the same physical size on your screen as 10 pixels would have on an mdpi (160 pixels/inch) screen.</strike>

It looks like you are applying the dp-to-pixels conversion twice. On an hdpi device, the ratio is 1.5 and you are getting the square of that (1.5<sup>2</sup> * 10 = 22.5). This is because of your call to `setTextSize(textsize)`. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28float%29):

> Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled pixel" units. This size is adjusted based on the current density and user font size preference.

Try using:

```
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textsize);
```

Comment: I don't think so, I'm running this on a hdpi device. I set the values by XML and the size is not the same as I get with this method.

Comment: @SergioCarneiro Which device?

Comment: 3.7 FWVGA slider. Has 240 pixels/inch.

Comment: @SergioCarneiro - What do you get with `mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textsize_small)`?

Comment: Yes you did. Good job. Thanks!